# Запись в двумерный массив из файла с#

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть текстовый файл, в котором записан двумерный массив целочисленных значений от 1 до 100 (матрица "10х10"). Необходимо считать данный массив из файла, вывести его в *textbox*, а затем найти среднее значение. В *WinForm* никак не могу разобраться, что за чем и как идет.

Comment: В каком формате записан массив? В остальном — тут три разных задачи (чтение из файла, заполнение массива из какого-то формата, вывести в текстбокс, найти среднее). С какой из этих задач у вас сложности?

Comment: @Алёна Хворова "никак не могу разобраться, что за чем и как идет" Например, 8 Марта идет за Новым Годом.

Comment: Бывает что и Новый Год идет за 8 Марта. ;-)

Comment: Формат видимо в виде матрицы, правда текстбокс для вывода будет кривоват, лучше наверное аналог типа дельфийского StringGrid-а похожее на DataGridView в винформс.

Answer (score 2):

В рамках недели домашних заданий на SO:

```
int size = 4;
// прочитать первые 10 строк файла
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\in.txt").Take(10).ToArray();

int[,] arr = new int[size, size];

// разобрать в массив
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int[] row = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        arr[i, j] = row[j];
    }
}

// вывести в текстбокс
for (int i = 0; i< size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        textBox1.Text += arr[i, j].ToString() + "\t";
    }

    textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
}

// посчитать среднее
MessageBox.Show(arr.Cast<int>().Average().ToString());
```